# Transact SQL: case when 1=1 then 0.5 else ceiling(sh) end /* returns 1 (!) why? */

Tags: sql-server, join, sum, case, ceil

```
-- Transact SQL:  case when 1=1 then 0.5 else ceiling(sh) end   /* returns 1  (!) why? */
declare @T table (h decimal(2,1)) 
insert @T (h) values (1.0)
select 
case when 1=1 then 0.5 else ceiling(sh) end   /* returns 1  (!) why? */
from @T T1
join (select sum(h) as sh from @T )T2  on 1 = 1
```

Comment: it is converting to int

Comment: @hogan why? I always thought the `CASE` took the first case type for the whole case?

Comment: Because ceiling(sh) returns int -- in a case where both sides of the case are different it will "upgrade" to int.  see @JuanCarlosOropeza code in his answer

Comment: Actually, it returns decimal(38,0)

Comment: @Hogan it doesn't return int and int doesn't have higher datatype precedence than decimal

Comment: yep... decimal not int.  that is more correct.

Comment: `select sum(h) as sh from @T` returns `numeric(38,1)` so not sure why the 1 precision gets lost

Comment: because it is not two sides of a case @MartinSmith.  case handling was always a pain.

Comment: oh that's the `CEILING` of course that makes it `numeric(38,0)`

Comment: @Hogan Yes I wrote that answer :) ... I know how to fix the problem. But I mean I though the CASE statement go for the first case to get the type, Like when you use `UNION`. So what is the logic to choose the datatype for the `CASE`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is nothing to do with the `int` datatype

- The literal `0.5` has a dataype of `decimal(1,1)`
- Applying `CEILING` on a `decimal(p,s)` returns a result of type
  `decimal(p,0)`
- Applying `SUM` on a `decimal(p,s)` returns a result of
  type `decimal(38,s)`
- With a mixed `CASE` expression that can return
  `decimal(p1,s1)` or `decimal(p2,s2)` the result will use the same rules as when `UNION`-ing these data types and have precision (`*`)
  of  `max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2)`    and scale of `max(s1, s2)`

> `*` The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a
>   result precision is greater than 38, it is reduced to 38, and the
>   corresponding scale is reduced to try to prevent the integral part of
>   a result from being truncated. ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017))

So your column `h` has datatype of `decimal(2,1)`, the datatype when `SUM` is applied is `decimal(38,1)`, the datatype of `CEILING` applied to that is `decimal(38,0)`. Then you use that in a `CASE` expression with `decimal(1,1)`

```
max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2)
max( 0,  1) + max(   38,     0) = 1 + 38 = 39
```

And

```
max(s1, s2) = max(0, 1) = 1
```

So the desired result datatype would be `decimal(39,1)`. This is larger than 38 so you get the scale reduction described above and end up with `decimal(38,0)` - `0.5` is rounded to `1` when cast to that datatype.

If you would rather keep the precision of the final result you can use

```
case when 1=1 then 0.5 else CAST(ceiling(sh) AS decimal(38,1)) end
```

There is a miniscule additional risk of overflow with this but to be hit by it the sum would need to add up to one of the following values

- `9999999999999999999999999999999999999.5`
- `9999999999999999999999999999999999999.6`
- `9999999999999999999999999999999999999.7`
- `9999999999999999999999999999999999999.8`
- `9999999999999999999999999999999999999.9`

such that the `SUM` itself fits into `38,1` but `CEILING` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

More explanation:

```
select CEILING(170.00/6.00),CEILING(170/6),170.00/6.00,170/6
```

Result:

```
29  28  28.333333   28
```

Answer (score -3):

As explain in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence. If the conversion is not a supported implicit conversion, an error is returned. When both operand expressions have the same data type, the result of the operation has that data type.

In your case is converted to `int` because has the bigger precedence.

**[sql demo](https://rextester.com/SYUG24330)**

```
declare @T table (h decimal(2,1)) 
insert @T (h) values (1.0)
select 
case when 1=1 then 0.5 else ceiling(sh)*1.0 end  -- << convert to float
from @T T1
join (select sum(h) as sh from @T )T2  on 1 = 1
```

Comment: two downvotes?  Maybe because you did not explain why it worked?

Comment: Not sure, but it might have to do something with the `float`. A proper solution would not leave the `decimal` domain.

Comment: @GSerg So maybe use cast on both statement to make sure has the same type? Just wondering how you can know what type is 0.5 converted in this case? I cant tell in my demo

Comment: No, it is converted to `decimal(38,0)` because [this is what `ceiling` returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560374/transact-sql-case-when-1-1-then-0-5-else-ceilingsh-end-returns-1-why#comment93987029_53560374). You are supposed to cast only the `ceiling` part back to a `decimal` with a decimal position.

Comment: @GSerg According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) ceiling `Return values have the same type as numeric_expression.` how you know is `decimal(38,0)` ?

Comment: I know because Martin Smith [said so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560374/transact-sql-case-when-1-1-then-0-5-else-ceilingsh-end-returns-1-why#comment93987029_53560374) and because `exec sp_describe_first_result_set N'select ceiling(sum(h)) from (values (cast(0.5 as decimal(2,1)))) T1(h)';` confirms it. Ceiling keeps the base type (numeric) but changes the precision. First `sum()` bumps it up to `(38,1)`, then `ceiling` rounds it down to `(38,0)`.

Comment: @GSerg ok, didnt knew about `exec sp_describe_first_result_set` still not sure why ceiling remove the precision when the documentation said will keep the same data type. Or why people keep downvoting :/

Comment: After replacing ceiling(sh) by ceiling(h),  the result is ok, 0.5.
The question is, why ceiling(sh) works not equally to ceiling(h)

Comment: Ok, let me dig a litle big. But you ask why return 1 and I already answer that isnt?

Comment: Are you sure? `ceiling(h)` is also 1

Comment: @PetrKral Because `ceiling(h)` gives `decimal(2,0)`, and between `(2,0)` and `(2,1)` the resulting type is `(3,1)`. On contrary, `sum()` pushes the size up to the maximum `(38)`, there cannot be `(39,1)`, so it ends up being `(38,0)`.